# how to convert "05:30" String value into integer using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, type-conversion

I tried to convert the string into integer using `parseInt` and `parseFloat`. But my string value is "+05:30" while using `parseInt` or `parseFloat` it converts it into 5, but I need exact conversion to 5.30. How could I do this?

My sample code is:

```
   User.findAll({attributes: ['UTC offset'],
                    where: {
                        Timezone: { $like: '%'+address }
                    }
                }).then(TimeZoneData => {
                    if(TimeZoneData.length != 0) {
                        var offset = parseFloat(TimeZoneData[0].dataValues['UTC DST offset']), // it return 5 only
                    }
```

Comment: please specify only **one** result you like to get.

Comment: Okay i need 5.30. I dont know how exactly 05:30 offset converted into integer. Thats y i mentioned both results

Comment: i need exact conversion of 05:30 as integer from string

Comment: You can just replace the `:` to `.`, `"5:30".replace(':','.')` if you want. Btw `5.30` is not an integer.

Comment: Okay @NisargShah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say the time zone offsets are valid, they are in hours and minutes always separated by a colon (':') and preceded by a '+' or '-'.

So

```
var utcOffset = "+05:30";
var a = uctOffset.split(':');
var hour = +a[0];
var minute = +a[1];
```

What you do with the hour and minute values is up to you - but if the hour is negative, the minutes might need to be made negative too. I suggest you use `isNaN` to check the  minute is valid if it may be absent:

```
if( isNaN( minute)
   minute = 0;
```